# Working with Azure Development Storage from command-line

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage

I need to upload some files to my Azure storage emulator using scripts. The same task for remote Azure storage is performed easily with Azure PowerShell cmdlets, just call

```
Add-Blob -BlobType Block -FilePath $myFilePath -ContainerName $myContainerName
```

But how can I do the same thing for local storage emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution using PowerShell Cmdlets.

You need to specify -UseDevelopmentStorage option to the cmdlets:

```
Get-Container -UseDevelopmentStorage
```

or

```
Add-Blob -UseDevelopmentStorage -BlobType Block -FilePath $myFilePath -ContainerName $myContainerName
```

Comment: Where do we get these cmdlets, they are not part of the current powershell sdk.

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for how to do this with Azure SDK (2.1), here is how:

```
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -Local
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $SourceFilePath `
    -Container $DestinationContainerName -Blob `
    $DestinationBlobName -Context $StorageContext
```

If you want to actually upload to an Azure storage account, change the $StorageContext:

```
New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
    -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Azure Command Line Tools, available here:

https://github.com/RobBlackwell/AzureCommandLineTools

They run on the normal command prompt, they're not actually powershell cmdlets.

```
SET AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING=UseDevelopmentStorage=true
PutBlob filename [containername[/blobname]]
```

Comment: Can you show the example how to use them with the development storage?

Comment: I have added an example of how to upload a file to a blob using development storage.

Comment: Thank you! I finally managed the same thing with Azure PowerShell Cmdlets, there is the same option -UseDevelopmentStorage :)